# Find k to make f(x) a probability density function

Tags: probability

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{kx^3}{(1+2x)^6} \space\space\space &x>0 \\0 &x\le0\end{cases}$$

Find $k$ so that $f(x)$ can serve as a probability density function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use the fact that if $f(x)$ defines a probability density function, then:$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \mathrm{d}x =1$$

Can you use this fact here?

**Edit:**

To integrate $I = \int \frac{x^3}{(1+2x)^6} dx$, use the substitution $u =1+2x$, to get, $$I = \frac{1}{16}\int \frac{(u-1)^3}{u^6} du$$

Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that. It is not the problem of me not knowing what to do, but it is that I couldn't solve the integration...

Comment: @Geophysics, this is why people ask that you provide some context instead of a problem statement. If you had explained in the OP that you knew what to do but did not know how to compute the integral, you would have saved Rohan some time.

Answer (score 1):

We must solve the integral $$\int_0^{\infty} k\frac{x^3}{(1+2x)^6}=k\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^3}{(1+2x)^6}=1$$

Apply integration by parts to solve

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^3}{(1+2x)^6}$$

Let $u=x^3$, $v' = \frac{1}{(1+2x)^6}$

Then  take

$$\begin{align*}
uv-\int vdu
\end{align*}$$

This is a pain to solve, but software should give you a result of $\frac{1}{320}$ so then $k$ must be $320$.

Answer (score 0):

It is a pain: Use partial fractions (thanks Maple etc):
$$\frac{x^3}{(1+2x)^6} = -\frac{3}{8(1+2x)^4} -\frac{1}{8(1+2x)^6}+\frac{3}{8(1+2x)^5}+\frac{1}{8(1+2x)^3}$$
You can then do the integrals with a simple substitution $y=1+2x$.
Eventually, you find $k=320$.